# formtastic radio collection add a name to the group

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic, radio-group

How do you add a name to a group of radio buttons in a formtastic radio button collection. I need to add a name attribute in order that the radio buttons are checked and unchecked properly when one is clicked. I've tried a couple of variations on

```
 <div class="product-image-form" >
   <%= semantic_form_for [:admin, product], remote: true do |f| %>
     <div class="product-images">
     <h4>Select image</h4>
     <%= f.input :selected_image_url, as: :radio, collection: product.product_images.map { |image| [image_tag(product_image.image_url).thumb, {class: selected_image_class(product,image)}), image.image_url,
    {'data-huge-image' => image.big_product_image} ]}, input_html: {name: {"product[selected_image_url"}} %>
  <%= f.actions %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The above form works but no name attribute is added to the radio button group.

The output starts with

```
<div class="radio_buttons input optional form-group" id="product_selected_image_url_input">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the formtastic form was not correctly registering when a radio button was clicked by setting the checked attribute to checked and unsetting this attribute on options not checked. My solution was to replace formtastic and use the rails helper radio_collection_button.

```
<div class="product-image-form" >
  <%= form_for [:admin, product], remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="product-images">
      <h4>Select image</h4>
      <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :selected_image_url, product.product_images, :image_url, :id  do |b| 
        b.label(:"data-huge-image" => "#{b.object.big_product_image}", class: selected_image_class(product,b.object)) { b.radio_button + image_tag("#{b.object.image_url}").thumb) }
      end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```